# docker swarm + jenkins CI

Tags: docker, jenkins, непрерывная-интеграция, docker-swarm

Категорически приветствую!

Имеется некий сайт, состоящий из frontend, backend, database - весь проект разворачивается в docker swarm через stackfile. 
Так же имеются тесты на java; и jenkins, который запускает их, идёт на вебморду и, собсно, тестит. Всё это живёт отдельно и никак друг с другом не пересекается.

Вопрос: А как мне это всё совместить? То есть я хочу создать в jenkins item, который бы при запуске, из гита сливал исходники и stack.yaml, поднимал локальную копию сайта, скачивал исходники тестов и прогонял тесты на локальной версии сайта.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте агентов к вашему `Jenkins`, на которых потом будет идти ваш CI. Например, с помощью плагина [Self-Organizing Swarm Modules](https://plugins.jenkins.io/swarm). Он деплоит `Docker Swarm` ноды, как слейвы `Jenkins`.
Затем нужно создать пайплайн (Jenkinsfile), в котором вы опишете на каком агенте, что нужно запускать с помощью команд Pipelines DSL (`sh 'docker build'`, `sh 'docker service create'`). Пайплайн может быть как [declarative](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline), так и [scripted](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline).

Несколько примеров, которые Вам могут помочь:

- [Simple CD pipeline demo at scale with Jenkins Swarm,Docker Swarm and Goland](https://github.com/krasi-georgiev/cd-demo/blob/master/Jenkinsfile) - scripted pipeline
- Пример с [declarative pipeline](https://gist.github.com/bvis/68f3ab6946134f7379c80f1a9132057a)

Comment: Есть один виртуальный сервер (нода) где установлен jenkins. Туда же нужно как-то поместить swarm (полагаю, просто установить docker, инициировать swarm из одной этой ноды и поставить jenkins) и на этом же одном хосте (одной ноде) - разворачивать stack и тестировать каким-то образом...

Comment: Это возможно сделать. Можно даже без установки дополнительных плагинов, но придется все манипуляции с Docker делать через `sh()` . [Еще один](https://engineering.riotgames.com/news/thinking-inside-container-dockercon-talk-and-story-so-far) хороший цикл статей по этой теме